# how do I import a file from the same parent directory in rust

Tags: rust

how do I import a module from the same parent directory in rust

```
├── main.rs
└── utils
    ├── circle.rs
    └── ray.rs
```

how do I import ray.rs from circle.rs

I tried using `mod ray;` in circle.rs but rust-analyzer is giving me the error `unresolved module, can't find module file: circle/ray.rs, or circle/ray/mod.rs`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create `utils.rs` next to `main.rs`, and then put the following in it.

```rs
mod circle;
mod ray;
```

This also works as `utils/mod.rs`, but `utils.rs` is preferred.

Ensure `main.rs` has `mod utils;`.

Then in `ray.rs` you can put one of the following.

```rs
use super::circle;
```

or

```rs
use crate::utils::circle;
```